# Fieldtype for radio buttons with extra option to provide input from user

Tags: fields

I need a Fieldtype that shows radion buttons for a user.

However I want an extra option for the user to provide text to a textfield if one of the options for the radio buttons is "other, ..."

Is this possible or is there a addon that can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for an field type add-on I use all the time called [*Entry Type*](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type). It provides *P&T Pill* buttons if you have that field type installed or Radio Buttons (I prefer P&T Pill), and hides or shows fields depending on which button is active.

Personally, I don't remember how on earth I got along without *Entry Type* before. Hope it works for you.

Here's a screenshot of the admin interface so you can get a feel for how it works:

[image: Entry Type Screenshot]

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I'd never heard of it before and, having given it a quick try, it looks incredibly useful. I've submitted an edit to your post that includes a demo screenshot so that people can get a sense of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a fieldtype that would do that natively, but it would be pretty straightforward to do this with two fields and a sprinkling of jQuery for some UI sugar.

Just create a second (text) field to hold your "other" content, then in your template do:

```
{if radio_field != "other"}
  {radio_field}
{if:else}
  {text_field}
{/if}
```

To make things a bit friendlier in the CP, you can take advantage of the fact that field instructions can contain HTML, *including* JavaScript. Basically we'll attach an event handler to the radio button's `change` event, inspect the current value of the radio button at that point, and toggle the visibility of our text field depending on whether that value is "other" or not. Something like this should do it (not very tested):

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var radioField = "your_radio_field_id",
      textField = "your_text_field_id",
      textFieldWrapper = "hold_field_" + textField.slice((textField.lastIndexOf("_")+1));

  $(document).on('change', '[name='+radioField+']', function(e){
    var $textFieldWrapper = $('#'+textFieldWrapper);
    if ($(this).val() = "other"){
      $textFieldWrapper.show();
    }
    else {
      $textFieldWrapper.hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

***NB** for this to work you'll need to look up your fields' `field_id` values in the database, as that's what's used in the publish/edit page markup. If this is too fragile for you or you want to do this with a large number of fields then you'd probably need a custom fieldtype.*

Comment: I only want this option in the backend when editing an entry. Not for filling in a form at the frontend.

Comment: yep, this JS would go in the instructions field for your radio field which is then shown (or in this case executed) on the publish/edit page in the CP